# Error trying to setup mysql with django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm new to django and I'm trying to connect it with mysql. I've never worked with setting up env variables before and I'm a bit confused as to this error when I run django-admin dbshell

```
(venv) dhcp-ccc-12919:project user$ django-admin dbshell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_fr
om_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 187, in get_lang
uage

    return _trans.get_language()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr
__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment v
ariable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

My DATABASE settings are

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'todo',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `manage.py` rather than `django-admin`, as that sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Following helps me is setting up Django with Mysql.

Step1: Install pymysql if not installed already.
       For windows use the command:

`easy_install.exe pymysql`

Step2: In the settings.py in the top write the following commands

```
import  pymysql

pymyql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Then in the settings.py change the database settings as follows,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<database_name>',
        'USER': '<mysql_username>',
        'PASSWORD' : '<password>',
        'HOST' : 'localhost',
        'PORT' : '3306',
    }
}
```

You may test the mysql connection from django shell by the following,

```
python manage.py shell
>>>from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
```

If there is no output to the above it means mysql setup is correct.

Hope it will work for you. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Why pymysql rather than mysqlclient?

Comment: never tried with mysqlclient. Apologies for not able to provide you a valid answer to your question: "Why pymysql rather than mysqlclient?"

Comment: None of this is in the slightest relevant to the original question.